# How often will the constructors and destructors be called when returning from a function?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

If I have a function like the following:

```
stack fillStack(){
  stack a;
  return a;
}

void main(){
  stack s=fillStack();
}
```

Consider we have a class called `stack`.
How many constructor and destructor will be called?

Comment: Title says one thing.. body another.

Comment: depends on compiler optimizations.

Comment: At most two, but as little as none are permissible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what **should** be happening:

```
stack fillStack() {
  stack a;  // constructor
  return a; // copy constructor and destructor a
}

int main(){
  stack s=fillStack(); // copy constructor and destructor of the temporary
} // destructor s
```

In practice the standard explicitly allows the copy-constructors to be
optimized away (this is called *copy elision*) and the value to be
constructed in place. That *could* end up looking something like this:

```
void fillStack(stack&);

int main() {
  stack s;
  fillStack(s); // with reference
}
```

Although, copy-construction must still be well-formed even if the
compiler applies this transformation. If copy-construction can have
side-effects this optimization can lead to somewhat odd behavior (try
printing something from the copy-constructor and observe the behavior
on different optimization levels).

This optimization becomes largely unnecessary with C++11 due to
move-semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming NO compiler optimization, it should be 2 Copy constructor calls - One from function local to return value temporary, one from return value temporary to `s`